# Confusion about probability density about p(x;w) and p(x|w), where w is the parameter

Tags: normal-distribution, probability-density

I can't understand the difference between p(x|w) and p(x;w),like this:
p(x|mu,sigma)=N(x|mu,sigma) and p(x;mu,sigma)=N(x;mu,sigma), where N is normal distribution.